# How to access to control property inside the template control?

Tags: wpf

I want to change control properties inside the template control. For example foreground . But when I change that noting happened. I set foreground to Aqua in the bellow code and after setting IsEnabled to false nothing happened (just opacity changed)

```
<CheckBox Name="chbx" Content="Check Box" Foreground="White"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" >
        <CheckBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <BulletDecorator>
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border Width="15" Height="15" x:Name="border"
                                Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="2"></DropShadowEffect>
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                                  Width="8"
                                  Height="8"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M 0 0 L 8 8 M 0 8 L 8 0"
                                  Stretch="Fill"
                                  Stroke="LightGray"
                                  StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                                  StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
                                  StrokeThickness="2"
                                />
                        </Border>

                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="04,0,0,0"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                    />    
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </CheckBox.Template>
    </CheckBox>
```

Comment: The ControlTemplate does not use the Foreground property. There should be some TemplateBinding, e.g. on the Stroke property of the Path.

Comment: The template of a checkbox has a grid with two columns in it. The check goes in the column 0 and content in column 1. You have put both your bulletdecorator and contentpresenter straight into the  template.